# Draw to framebuffer object, then blit to primary display (GLES 3.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-3.0

I am attempting to create a framebuffer object, and then blit it to the primary display. The purpose of this to to cache a screen shot that I can blit to the display whenever I want without re-rendering the object. I am using Open GLES 3.0 with android NDK.

I created a frame buffer in the normal way.

```
GLuint framebuffer = NULL;
glGenFramebuffers( 1, &framebuffer );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );

GLuint colorRenderBuffer = NULL;        
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &colorRenderbuffer );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer );
glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, engine->width, engine->height );
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer );

GLuint depthRenderbuffer = NULL;
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &depthRenderbuffer );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer );
glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, engine->width, engine->height );
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer );

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    LOGI( "failed to make complete framebuffer object %d", status );
}
else {
    LOGI( "Frame buffer is complete." );
}
```

This works without error. I then am able to edit the frame buffer, successfully.

```
glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );

// Just fill the screen with a color.
glClearColor( red, green, blue, 255 );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

read_pixels( ); //wrapper for glReadPixels. Shows that all pixels in the frame buffer object have the desired color.
```

However, attempting to blit this to the main draw buffer fails.

```
glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );

glReadBuffer( GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 );

glBlitFramebuffer( 0, 0, engine->width, engine->height, 0, 0, engine->width, engine->height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR );

LOGI("GL error after blit: %d", glGetError()); //no error reported

glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );

read_pixels( engine ); //gives zero'd buffer (wrong result)

eglSwapBuffers( engine->display, engine->surface ); //shows a black screen, unless I use glClearColor directly on the primary display buffer.
```

Comment: So no errors, but no set pixels? What version of Android are you using? (I had some trouble with `glBlitFramebuffer()` due to driver bugs on Android 4.x, but I believe the issue I had was fixed in 5.0. https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java#L920 )

Comment: Yes, no errors and no set pixels. I've seen the issue with Android version 4.4.2 and 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the problem by using a texture (instead of a render buffer) frame buffer object, drawing to that frame buffer, and then drawing that frame buffer texture to the default buffer. This isn't really an answer, but a work around, so I'd still appreciate it if anyone has an answer to the original question.

For reference, I include the key code below:

```
GLuint LoadFrameBufferTexture( ESContext *context, int width, int height ) {

    glGenFramebuffers( 1, &(context->framebuffer) );
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, context->framebuffer );

    // create the texture
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );
    glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0 );

    GLuint depthRenderbuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &depthRenderbuffer );
    glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer );
    glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height );
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer );


    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        LOGI("failed to make complete framebuffer object ");
    }   else {
        LOGI("Frame buffer is complete.");
    }

    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );

    return texture;
}

void draw_frame(int red, int green, int blue) {
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, esContext->framebuffer );
    glClearColor( red, green, blue, 255 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
    DrawFrame( esContext );

    eglSwapBuffers( engine->display, engine->surface );
}   

void DrawFrame( ESContext *esContext ) {
    UserData *userData = (UserData *)esContext->userData;
    GLfloat vVertices[] = {-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
    glViewport( 0, 0, esContext->width, esContext->height );
    glUseProgram( userData->programObject );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof( GLfloat ), vVertices );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof( GLfloat ), &vVertices[3] );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, userData->frameTexId );
    glUniform1i( userData->baseMapLoc, 0 ); 
    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices );
}
```